# BroadcastReceiver not receiving even after all the permissions in place

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have an issue that my receiver doesnt receive... How strange...

I feel like I read every other post on stackoverflow, but nothing works.

Target is Android 10, device is also running android 10 and this is my receiver.

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Name = "com.meac.ReaderService.BootComplete", Enabled = true, Exported = true, Permission = "RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED")]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionBootCompleted })]
    public class BootComplete : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            
            string text = "Boot completed";
            ToastLength duration = ToastLength.Short;

            var toast = Toast.MakeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.Show();
        /*    if (intent.Action.Equals(Intent.ActionBootCompleted))
            {
                Intent s = new Intent(context, typeof(ReaderService));

                context.StartService(s);

                Intent s2 = new Intent(context, typeof(GuardService));

                context.StartService(s);

               // StartRDP(context);
            }*/
        }
    }
```

And this is my manifest, which should contain all needed permissions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
    This code was generated by a tool.
    It was generated from C:\Users\tomas.filip\source\repos\ReaderService_V2\ReaderService_V2\Properties\AndroidManifest.xml
    Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
    the contents are regenerated.
-->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.meac.ReaderService" android:installLocation="internalOnly" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="27" android:targetSdkVersion="29" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTANT_APP_FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PERSISTENT_ACTIVITY" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
  <application android:name="android.app.Application" android:allowBackup="true" android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" android:debuggable="true" android:extractNativeLibs="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <receiver android:name="com.meac.ReaderService.BootComplete" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:permission="RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="crc64bdb27b5d294e9832.GuardService" />
    <activity android:name="crc64bdb27b5d294e9832.MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name="crc64bdb27b5d294e9832.ReaderService" />
    <activity android:name="crc646957603ea1820544.MediaPickerActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|uiMode" />
    <service android:name="crc64396a3fe5f8138e3f.KeepAliveService" />
    <receiver android:name="crc64a0e0a82d0db9a07d.BatteryBroadcastReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:label="Essentials Battery Broadcast Receiver" />
    <receiver android:name="crc64a0e0a82d0db9a07d.EnergySaverBroadcastReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:label="Essentials Energy Saver Broadcast Receiver" />
    <receiver android:name="crc64a0e0a82d0db9a07d.ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:label="Essentials Connectivity Broadcast Receiver" />
    <activity android:name="crc64a0e0a82d0db9a07d.IntermediateActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
    <provider android:name="xamarin.essentials.fileProvider" android:authorities="com.meac.ReaderService.fileProvider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
      <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/xamarin_essentials_fileprovider_file_paths" />
    </provider>
    <activity android:name="crc64a0e0a82d0db9a07d.WebAuthenticatorIntermediateActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
    <provider android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider" android:authorities="com.meac.ReaderService.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="1999999999" />
    <!-- suppress ExportedReceiver -->
    <receiver android:name="mono.android.Seppuku">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="mono.android.intent.action.SEPPUKU" />
        <category android:name="mono.android.intent.category.SEPPUKU.com.meac.ReaderService" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

I have manually enabled display over other apps permission.

I have spent on it 6 hours today and I am completely lost.

It will be 100% something stupid.

Hope so someone who can understand that can look into that. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tested your receiver on older version before Android 8.0? In Android 8.0 (API 26 and above), Google placed limitations on what apps can do while users aren't directly interacting with them. Check the limitations: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed that by adding categories into the intent filter.

```
[IntentFilter(actions: new[] { Intent.ActionBootCompleted }, Categories = new []{ Intent.CategoryDefault })]
```